# mPDF 6.0 Custom Progress Bar Issue

Tags: php, css, mpdf

I'm using mpdf 6.0.

The issue is when I css as 10%

```
<div class="progressbar">
                        <div class="progressbar-value bg-color-green" style="width: 10%; overflow: hidden;"> &nbsp;10%</div>
                    </div>
```

The result as:
[image: 10%]

And when I add 3%, it covers the whole width

```
<div class="progressbar">
                            <div class="progressbar-value bg-color-green" style="width: 3%; overflow: hidden;"> &nbsp;3%</div>
                        </div>
```

The result is:

[image: 3%]

Please guide me to solve this problem.

PHP:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(600);
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");

require 'mpdf.php';


$mpdf = new \mPDF();



$html = "";

        $html .= <<<EOD
                    <div class="progressbar">
                        <div class="progressbar-value bg-color-green" style="width: 3%; overflow: hidden;"> &nbsp;11%</div>
                    </div>

EOD;

$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);

$mpdf->Output('','I');  


exit;
?>
```

CSS (style.css):

```
.progress, .progress-bar, .progressbar {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
}
.progressbar-value {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.text-left {
    text-align: left !important;
}
.bg-color-green {
    background-color: #61BD4F;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above issue by using `background: linear-gradient() and background-size: x%`

```
<div class="progressbar" style="float:left;">
  <div class="progressbar-value" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #00FF00 100%); background-size:3%;float:left; height:15px;width:100%;">
    <div class="text" style="text-align: left; float: left;display:block;font-size:12px;height:15px;">3%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the result is

[image: Issue solved]